# Complex analysis 2: $f \in \mathcal{H}(U,F)$

Tags: complex-analysis, normed-spaces

I have a problem:

Suppose $U$ is an open set in $E$ and $f \in \mathcal{H}(U,F)$.

Prove that:

$1/.$ If $U=E$ then $r_bf(x)=\infty, \forall x \in U$;

$2/.$ If $U \ne E$ then $r_bf(x)< \infty, \forall x \in U$.

And case "$2$"; We have $$|r_bf(x)-r_bf(y)| \le \left \|x-y  \right \|, \forall x,y \in U$$.

Where $r_bf(x)=\sup \{r>0:f(x)\ \text{is bounded on}\ \overline{B}(x,r) \subset U\}$

Comment: This question is hard to understand. You might consider rewriting it with more explanation and detail. It's very hard to tell what exactly is being asked.

Comment: I have fixed it. Potato.

Comment: Could you explain what $\mathcal H(U,F)$ is? I'm guessing the holomorphic functions on $U$, but I don't know what the $F$ means.

Comment: It's also unclear what you mean by $r_bf(x)$. You seem to be using $x$ for two different things. Also, what is $E$? Any domain?

Comment: Yes, Potato. $f$ is holomorphic function (cf. Analytic function).1/ $E$ and $F$ are two complex Banach spaces.                                                    2/ Let $U$ be an open set in $E$. The mapping $f: U \to F$ is called holomorphic function, if for all $a \in U$, there exists $\mathbb {B} (a, r) \subset U$ and a sequence of polynomials $P_m \in \mathcal{P}(^mE,F)$ such that $f(x) = \sum_{0}^{\infty}P_m(x-a)$ is Uniform convergence, with $x \in \mathbb{B}(a,r)$. We denoted by $\mathcal{H}(U,F)$ is the vector space of holomorphic mapping from $U$ into $F$.

Comment: 3/ We denoted by $\mathcal{P}(^mE,F)$ the vector space of all $m$ - homogeneous (continuous) polynomials from $E$ into $F$. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_polynomial

4/. The map $P:E \to F$ is called polynomial of degree $m$, if:
$P=P_0+ \ldots +P_m$, $\forall P_j \in \mathcal{P}_a(^jE,F)$,$j=0,\ldots , m$ .

Comment: I hope that I have explained it with more explanation and detail. If it isn't clear, you might ask. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

We assume $r_bf(x)=+\infty$ **and** $r_bf(y)<+\infty$.
Let $\forall r>0$ we have:
$$\overline{B}(y,r) \subset \overline{B}(x,r+\left \| x-y \right \|)$$

$\implies \sup \left \{\left \|f(t)  \right \|:t \in \overline{B}(y,r)  \right \} $
$\le \sup \left \{\left \|f(t)  \right \|: t \in \overline{B}(x,r+\left \| x-y \right \|) \right \} < + \infty$

$\implies r_bf(y)=\infty$ (Conflict).

2.1/ If $r_bf(x)< \infty,\ r_bf(y)< \infty,\ \forall x,y \in U$

How we can prove that: 
$$|r_bf(x)-r_bf(y)| \le \left \|x-y  \right \|, \forall x,y \in U$$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Part 2: by symmetry it suffices to prove that 
$$r_bf(x)-r_bf(y)\le \|x-y\| \tag1$$
(exchanging $x$ and $y$ gives the other part of the desired inequality). If $r_bf(x)\le \|x-y\|$, we already have (1). Otherwise, take any $r$ such that $0<r<r_bf(x)- \|x-y\|$. Note that 
$f$ is bounded on $\overline B(x,r+\|x-y\|)$. It was  already observed that     $\overline{B}(y,r) \subset \overline{B}(x,r+\left \| x-y \right \|)$. Hence, $f$ is bounded on $\overline{B}(y,r)$. The conclusion is that $r_bf(y)\ge r - \|x-y\|$, and since $r$ can be arbitrarily close to $r_bf(x)$, (1) follows.

By the way, it's impossible to have infinite $r_bf(x)$ when $U$ is not the entire space. The definition of $r_bf(x)$ implies $r_bf(x)\le \operatorname{dist}(x,E\setminus U)$, and the quantity on the right is finite unless $E=U$.